# Why do we always have to use complete induction when dealing with a sequence defined recursively?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I heard I should for simplicity use complete induction (strong induction) always rather than memorize when to use weak induction versus complete induction. Is there a reason that I should always use strong induction when dealing with recursive sequences? I'm not looking for an explanation on strong vs weak induction because I heard I'm always correct if I use strong induction.

Comment: [both induction are equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1978715/why-induction-is-defined-as-an-implication-instead-of-an-if-and-only-if-statem) yes. Sometimes you can use only weak for recursions too. I think it depends on the kind of recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you "hear that"?

I think that simplicity suggests that you use the simplest tool that does the job. So when ordinary vanilla induction works it's the tool of choice. Save strong induction for the problems where it's necessary. That depends on the problem, not on something you memorize.